# Wordpress Rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, rewrite-rules, profiles

I'm trying to get http://example.com/site/vendors/?u=abc to rewrite to http://example.com/site/vendors/abc but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the url rewrites to work.

/site/ is the root directory for my WP installation
/vendors/ is a page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming `u` is a custom query var, you have to first add it to the array of recognized query vars:

```
function wpa_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'u';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'wpa_query_vars');
```

Then add an internal rewrite rule that accepts anything appended to `vendors` and passes that as the `u` query var:

```
function wpa_rewrite(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'vendors/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=vendors&u=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa_rewrite' );
```

Make sure to [flush rewrite rules](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) once for this rule to be added, you can also do this by just visiting the `Settings > Permalinks` admin page.

Then in the template, you can access the value of `u` via [`get_query_var()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var):

```
$vendor = get_query_var( 'u' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteRule ^/site/vendors/([^/]*)$ /site/vendors/?u=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I'm afraid he was asking about doing this with WP_Rewrite, not with mod_rewrite in .htaccess ;)

Comment: Great attempt David, I thank you for spending the time helping me